# Strange compiler speed optimization results - IAR compiler

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

I'm experiencing a strange issue when I try to compile two source files that contain some important computing algorithms that need to be highly optimized for speed.

**Initially**, I have two source files, let's call them `A.c` and `B.c`, each containing multiple functions that call each other (functions from a file may call functions from the other file). I compile both files with full speed optimizations and then when I run the main algorithm in an application, it takes **900 ms** to run.

**Then** I notice the functions from the two files are mixed up from a logical point of view, so I move some functions from `A.c` to `B.c`; let's call the new files `A2.c` and `B2.c`. I also update the two headers `A.h` and `B.h` by moving the corresponding declarations.

**Moving function definitions from one file to the other is the only modification I make!**

The strange result is that after I compile the two files again with the same optimizations, the algorithm now takes **1000 ms** to run.

What is going on here?

What I suspect happens: when functions `f` calls function `g`, being in the same file allows the compiler to replace actual function calls with inline code as an optimization. This is no longer possible when definitions are not compiled at the same time.

1. Am I correct in my assumption?
2. Aside from regrouping the function definitions as it was before, is there anything I can do to obtain the same optimization as before? I researched and it seems it's not possible to compile two source files simultaneously into a single object file. Could the order of compilation matter?

Comment: 1. it's possible, but modern compilers nowadays feature link-time optimization (LTO). Try turning it on if your compiler does.

Comment: Try turning on *Multi-file Compilation* in project settings. At least  IAR ARM compiler has it. Warning: It can seriously increase your compilation times.

Comment: Also, you might want to specify your platform. Maybe you are using some kind segmented memory where cost of function call depends on how far the it is from the point of call. I am not an expert in such matter, but someone else might be.

Answer (score 3):

As to whether your assumption is correct, the best way to tell is to examine the assembler output, such as by using `gcc -S` or `gcc -save-temps`. *That* will be the definitive way to see what your compiler has done.

As to compiling two C source files into a single object file, that's *certainly* doable. Just create a `AB.c` as follows:

```
#include "A.c"
#include "B.c"
```

and compile *that.*

Barring things that *should* be kept separate (such as static items which may exist in both C files), that should work (or at least work with a little modification).

However, remember the optimisation mantra: *Measure, don't guess!* You're giving up a fair bit of encapsulation by combining them so make sure the benefits well outweigh the costs.

Comment: Also `-save-temps` allows to see assembly while still producing binaries.

Comment: As an alternative to creating AB.c, you could create a Makefile target which concatenates the two files together, then compiles them.   But first try the link time optimizer, which is not a hack like putting the files together.